# Trying to recover deleted Ubuntu partition

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, data-loss

I made a mistake in logging into my 200 GB Ubuntu partition. I could not access Grub after that. Using a live CD I then ran Boot_Repair and apparently deleted the partition, I guess because I ran it from my 70 GB Windows partition. I can send the results of boot_info before that and of Boot_Repair. Then I ran TestDisk, which apparently only found `dev/sda/ -320GB / 298 / GiB - WDC - WD3200BEVT-22A23T0`.

Was there any more I could have done with TestDisk? I looked at the TestDisk_Step_By_Step example and found no way forward given that no other partitions turned up

I have run gpart and found this:

```
/sda1 - 15 GB
/sda2 - system reserved
/sda3 - 70.15 GB
/sda4 - extended 212.84
unallocated - 209.10
/sda5 - unknown 3.74 .
```

I have been told I can recover the partition using gparted's Rescue start end command, but I don't know what to enter for start and end.

**EDIT**: TestDisk Deeper Search stated that "the following partitions can't be recovered" and listed a 220-GB Linux partition 6 times. Then it stated that "The current number of heads per cylinder is 255 but the correct value may be 128" and I could try to change it in the Geometry menu (because apparently these are overlapping partitions) 
So should I do that?

Comment: test disk has options to search for lost partitions - http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#Quick_Search_for_partitions

Answer (score 2):

Since you have "unallocated" space (and only one chunk of it), as long as you *only deleted one partition*, I'd suggest using GParted (or your partition editor of choice) to create a new partition consuming all the free space, then mounting it read-only (`mount -o ro /dev/sdaX /mnt/`). As long as you mount it read-only, you shouldn't lose any more data.

**Make sure you don't accidentally format the partition in the process!** Namely, choosing a filesystem type in GParted will make it format the partition.

Comment: Thanks. I did reinstall in the linux partition after a previous mistake--but I hope that doesn't matter -- it wasn't deleted. but wouldn't I need to write the recovered data somewhere--i.e. what can be done to recover it once it is mounted read only?

Comment: If you can mount the partition read-only, then you can just mount it read-write. You don't have to do anything to get your data back, if you can mount it read-only, you can just use it however you did before. The only point of mounting it read-only first is so things don't get more messed up if it doesn't work.

Comment: I also should note that you may not want to use GParted, and use `fdisk` instead. GParted has a nasty habit of running `mkfs` for you if you're not careful, which will format the partition, and make it much harder and/or impossible to get your data back.